# Take number input from browser

Tags: php, html, jquery, keyboard, user-input

I want to take the number input from the user by clicking the display shown below (along with the ability to enter numbers using the keyboard).  [image]

Can you please suggest any good libraries that will help me do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use keypress event .

In HTML:

```
<element onkeypress="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

In JavaScript:

```
object.onkeypress=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

you can view more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)